# Allow and dissallow directory with # in robots.txt

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I'd like to block and unblock following URL formats:

Allow:`https://example.com/buyer/#/search/catalog/Lubricating-Oils/Automotive-Lubricants`

Dissallow:`https://example.com/buyer/#/search/product-description?sku=16087`

Due to `#` in URLs, both are getting allowed or disallowed at a time.

Comment: # is for within page navigation. It is not for producing distinct pages. Think about it, they are the same page.

Comment: These are SPA pages that is the reason # is present

Comment: You can't use robots.txt for this because those are client side-only URLs.  The only part of that URL that gets crawled is `https://example.com/buyer/`.  See [How to disallow hash fragments in robots.txt file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110568/how-to-disallow-hash-fragments-in-robots-txt-file)

Answer (score 1):

**#** is used as a comment character in **robots.txt**

> The # character marks the beginning of a comment.

[From Google's Create a robots.txt file](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt)

It does not say that `#` can be escaped.  Furthermore

> Valid robots.txt lines consists of a field, a colon, and a value. Spaces are optional, but recommended to improve readability. Space at the beginning and at the end of the line is ignored. To include comments, precede your comment with the # character. Keep in mind that everything after the # character will be ignored. The general format is :<#optional-comment>.

[How Google interprets the robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt)

The robots.txt file crawlers do not care if you have a **SPA** or a **PWA**.  I have written a SPA as well.  I used params  **`?name=value`** for pages.  And you can put these in **robots.txt**.